# Heroku Logs - open log referred to in error message

Tags: node.js, logging, error-handling, heroku

I'm deploying a node.js app to heroku (cedar stack)

I've set the NODE_ENV like this:

> heroku config:add NODE_ENV=production

I then do:

> git push heroku

However, after starting (i've got a console.log generating the first log entry) the app crashes.

I run:

> heroku logs

and get the below error.

How can I open the /app/log/production.log that it's referring to?

```
app[web.1]: listening on port 32168 within production environment
app[web.1]: 
app[web.1]: events.js:48
app[web.1]:         throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
app[web.1]:                        ^
app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT, open '/app/log/production.log'
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting means that it's trying to open '/app/log/production.log' and is unable to do so.  So find out where this logging is being attempted and disable or change it.

According to Heroku you should just be sending your application logs to STDOUT:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

So a console.log should be sufficient.